# Munki Setup - Cannot find /usr/local/munki

Tags: python, macos

https://github.com/munki/munki/wiki/Demonstration-Setup

On the page above, I have got as far as “Populating the repo” > “The tools you’ll use as an administrator are available from the command-line…”. However I cannot find /usr/local/munki . What do I need top do?

Answer (score 0):

this is a bit of a late answer, but I've stumbled across this question while investigating a separate issue.

**You'll likely need to make sure you've installed the latest version of MunkiTools:
https://github.com/munki/munki/releases/latest**

This should populate your `/usr/local/munki` directory with all the necessary tools to complete the demo setup and add `/usr/local/munki` to your `$PATH` (through the "munki" file in `/etc/paths.d`).  If your curious about what exactly a pkg installs/runs, you can use a 3rd-party tool such as [Suspicious Package](https://www.mothersruin.com/software/SuspiciousPackage/) or the bultin `pkgutil` command: `pkgutil --expand <pkg-path> <dir-path>` to take a look inside.

It looks like the Munki Wiki links to some discussion groups if you have any munki-specific questions:
https://github.com/munki/munki/wiki/Discussion-Group